# Tirando Print Screen C#

Tags: c#, windows, jogos, directx

Existe um jogo chamado Tibia (Em modo janela mesmo) que ao tentar tirar uma print screen o jogo acaba ofuscando a imagem deixando apenas a tela do jogo toda preta independente se o print foi originado da tecla de PrintScreen, ou de alguma função via código c#.

Já tentei de algumas maneiras fazer a captura da imagem do jogo porém sem sucesso.

Não sei exatamente o que eles fazem que conseguem ofuscar do print somente a janela do game em questão.

Tentei de dois modos:

```
Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
```

O segundo:

```
        public static Bitmap GetDesktopImage()
        {
            WIN32_API.SIZE size;

            IntPtr hDC = WIN32_API.GetDC(WIN32_API.GetDesktopWindow());
            IntPtr hMemDC = WIN32_API.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

            size.cx = WIN32_API.GetSystemMetrics(WIN32_API.SM_CXSCREEN);
            size.cy = WIN32_API.GetSystemMetrics(WIN32_API.SM_CYSCREEN);

            m_HBitmap = WIN32_API.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx, size.cy);

            if (m_HBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)WIN32_API.SelectObject(hMemDC, m_HBitmap);
                WIN32_API.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, size.cx, size.cy, hDC, 0, 0, WIN32_API.SRCCOPY);
                WIN32_API.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
                WIN32_API.DeleteDC(hMemDC);
                WIN32_API.ReleaseDC(WIN32_API.GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);
                return System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(m_HBitmap);
            }
            return null;
        }

public class WIN32_API
    {
        public struct SIZE
        {
            public int cx;
            public int cy;
        }
        public const int SRCCOPY = 13369376;
        public const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
        public const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteDC")]
        public static extern IntPtr DeleteDC(IntPtr hDc);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
        public static extern IntPtr DeleteObject(IntPtr hDc);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "BitBlt")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int xDest, int yDest, int wDest, int hDest, IntPtr hdcSource, int xSrc, int ySrc, int RasterOp);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateCompatibleBitmap")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateCompatibleDC")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SelectObject")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr bmp);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDC")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr ptr);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemMetrics")]
        public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int abc);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowDC")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(Int32 ptr);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReleaseDC")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDc);
    }
```

Há alguma outra maneira para tirar print e evitar essa ofuscação?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de bloqueio desse programa? Ele bloqueia o vento de print como um todo ou bloqueia ofusca a imagem dele? Sem saber qual ou como o programa funciona é difícil postar uma resposta assertiva, sendo impossível reproduzir o comportamento. E se o programa faz esse bloqueio, deve ser por algum bom motivo... Será que você deveria estar tentando realmente fazer isso?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Editei a pergunta explicando que é apenas a janela que sai preta e qualquer outro elemento é impresso no print normalmente.

Comment: um programa de gravar a tela, funciona ?

Comment: Vou tentar, mas qual o motivo do teste?

Comment: tentar entender como o bloqueio dele funciona... rs

Comment: dei uma pesquisada aqui... na verdade há um service "battleye" que faz esse bloqueio. Uma opção para contornar esse problema, é definir uma tecla de atalho para o printscreen dentro do jogo, e no C#, ler a pasta destino e enviar a tecla de atalho

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Eu ate explorei um pouco dessa opção e até funciona porém perco muito tempo de processamento na função de GetFiles() pra buscar a printScreen

Comment: use um `FileSystemWatcher`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Mesmo utilizando o FileSystemWatcher ficou muito mal optimizado, realmente necessitava de algo mais direto como um printscreen mesmo. 500~800ms só até o jogo criar o arquivo na pasta e eu carregar essa imagem pra ler. Tempo que nao posso perder :(

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Tentei gravar a tela com o OBS e sim ele funciona

Comment: @VictorLaio por que não usa a [API do OBS](https://obsproject.com/docs/reference-core.html) então? [Aqui](https://github.com/GoaLitiuM/libobs-sharp) tem o wrapper para .NET.

Comment: dando uma pesquisada, li algo sobre o battleye fazer uma varredura a cada 100 segundos e então pegar os processos que estão capturando algo do jogo. Eu faria um teste usando esse segundo código seu, mas rodando em processos diferentes, um exe para capturar a tela e outro para processar... então cada captura terá um pid diferente ou pelo menos a cada intervalo de tempo

Comment: instalei o jogo em uma vm, e o segundo código funciona normalmente... pelo menos na introdução e tutorial... tá ok (win 7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir sem entender como o DirectX funciona antes.

Jogos têm um ambiente de renderização isolado do sistema operacional, e no seu código está a utilizar a API do Windows para capturar o Stream de imagem na tela para um buffer dedicado. Isso até funcionará em jogos que executam em janela (ou jogos de janela cheia sem bordas), uma vez que ainda estão sendo renderizados no ambiente do sistema operacional e não outro.

Quando um aplicativo Direct3D entra em modo de tela cheia (tela cheia total e não janela sem bordas), ele ganha acesso total ao hardware gráfico, criando então um ambiente de renderização totalmente isolado do sistema operacional. Neste caso, você não poderá acessar a imagem da tela [buffer de imagem] sem passar pela placa de vídeo antes.

Hardwares da Nvidia têm o ShadowPlay. Os da AMD têm o Relive. O próprio Windows 10 tem o Xbox DVR. Todos capturam a imagem de forma isolada. O do Xbox faz diferente porquê ele obtém a imagem após ser exibida na tela. Os outros capturam antes da imagem ser exibida, após o processamento da placa de vídeo.

Os gravadores de terceiros normalmente injetam uma biblioteca que garante a cópia do buffer para outro destino, podendo então capturar a tela. Eles não são pegos por sistemas anti-batotas porque muitas vezes são conhecidos e os protetores adicionam exceções à eles.

No seu caso, você deveria utilizar uma API de terceiro para capturar imagem dedicada à jogos. Se quiser se aventurar e escrever a própria, lembre-se que deverá ser seguro para passar pelo sistema anti-chat do jogo.

### Atualização

Também vi que o [Tibia possui um mecanismo anti-screenshot](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/general-programming-and-reversing/360057-bypassing-game-anti-screenshot.html), no qual bloqueia capturas de tela independente se está em tela cheia ou em janela. Mas [aqui](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/2602154-post6.html) encontraram uma forma de burlar este problema, chamando a janela do Tibia, enviando o comando de screenshot e obtendo a imagem da screenshot.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

void KeyDown(IntPtr hwnd, int vk_key)
{
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, vk_key, (int)((MapVirtualKey((uint)vk_key, 0)) * 0x10000 + 1));
}

...

KeyDown(hWnd, 0x50);
```

Após isso, a captura de tela estará disponível em `...\AppData\Local\Tibia\packages\Tibia\screenshots`. Você pode usar I/O para obter o arquivo.

Note que você deverá associar a tecla <kbd>P</kbd> para Screenshots no jogo.

Comment: Eu cheguei a encontrar este forum explicando o que o cara fez e eu também realizei esta mesma ação, porém como comentei com Rovann Linhares, ela me toma cerca de 800ms desde o momento em que a print é tirada até o momento do carregamento dela no código e tenho que ficar verificando praticamente a cada 500ms se algo mudou na imagem. Será que conseguiria me ajudar com a ideia do OBS?

Comment: Creio que com ele eu conseguiria sim realizar o que preciso porém estou começando na parte de programação visual.

Comment: Tente implementar primeiro. Se ficar encalhado em um problema, venha aqui no SOpt que iremos te ajudar. Infelizmente, essa é a única maneira que encontrei de tirar print do seu jogo e tem a desvantagem do tempo de captura, mas é a solução que pude apresentar.

Comment: cara, eu fiz um hack pro tibia uma vez que pegava a cor do pixel em determinado ponto pra saber por exemplo se a barra de mana estava cheia e depois simulava digitar as palavras de alguma magia pra gastar mana. Funcionava normalmente. Usei somente a api do windows. Se dava pra pegar a cor de pontos específicos da tela deve dar pra fazer um print também.

Comment: @VictorLaio se essa resposta resolveu o problema dessa pergunta, considere marcá-la como correta logo abaixo dos botões de voto. Obrigado!